# select left join table use and condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

these two query output different result,
I have question  `AND m.status = $1 ...`each condition follow the left join table or move to the final part, thats different ??

query 1

```
SELECT count(mua.*) 
  AS total_row_count
  FROM media_user_action mua
    LEFT JOIN media m ON m.id = mua.media_id
      AND m.status = $1
    LEFT JOIN gallery_media gm ON gm.id = mua.media_id
    LEFT JOIN gallery g ON g.id = gm.gallery_id
      AND g.status = $1
    LEFT JOIN "user" mcbu ON mcbu.id = m.create_by_user_id
      AND mcbu.status = $1
    LEFT JOIN "user" gcbu ON gcbu.id = g.create_by_user_id
      AND gcbu.status = $1
WHERE mua.user_id = $2
```

query 2

```
SELECT count(mua.*) 
  AS total_row_count
  FROM media_user_action mua
    LEFT JOIN media m ON m.id = mua.media_id
    LEFT JOIN gallery_media gm ON gm.id = mua.media_id
    LEFT JOIN gallery g ON g.id = gm.gallery_id
    LEFT JOIN "user" mcbu ON mcbu.id = m.create_by_user_id
    LEFT JOIN "user" gcbu ON gcbu.id = g.create_by_user_id
WHERE 
m.status = $1
AND g.status = $1
AND mcbu.status = $1
AND gcbu.status = $1
AND mua.user_id = $2
```

**UPDATE**
base on below answer

if I want make sure return result, must all related/left join table status both equal $1, ( join table recode could be null) so I have to add `AND x.status ..` follow the join table, right?

Comment: are you asking "which of the two should you use?"?  Because the answer would depend on your intent.

Comment: thanks for reply, I want to select each related table all status are both equal $1 and where mua.user_id = $2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use left outer join, value of the right table may be `NULL`.

For simplicity's sake, let say we have

`Table A (id, name)` and `Table B (fid, status)`

Then query1 will be like

```
select A.id, B.status 
from A
left join (select * from B where status = $1)
on A.id = B.fid;
```

so result could have B.status is `NULL`

And query2 will be like

```
select C.* 
from (select A.id, B.status 
      from A
      left join B
      on A.id = B.fid
) C
where C.status = $1;
```

It's equal to

```
select * 
from A
inner join B
on A.id = B.fid
where B.status = $1;
```

So B.status must `exactly` be $1, and is never `NULL`

Comment: thanks for the example, does that means if I want to select/filter both A, B status both equal $1 .  and if B may be null then I should use query1, and if B always not null then I can also use query2 ?

Comment: It's depend on your intention. Let say: We have a guy `A`.  All friends who know (**id**) `A` are smart (**status**). Now 1.You must get list of all people who know A (some friends `A` know - `NOT NULL`, some strangers `A` don't know - `NULL`) => **query1**. 2.You must get all friends who know `A` (`not null`) => **query2**.

Answer (score 2):

When you put `WHERE` conditions on tables that you have `LEFT JOIN`-ed, and that require some their fields to have non-NULL values, then you are actually converting the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

This is because a `LEFT JOIN` may produce results where the joined table has no matching record. In that case all fields of that "virtual" record have value `NULL`. So by requiring that one of those fields is not null, you remove those instances from the result.

If on the contrary, you put such conditions in the `LEFT JOIN` condition, then you do not break this mechanism, where the a non-match will still give a result, albeit with `NULL`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, so if I'm sure the join table are not null then I can put the `and ...` at the final or if the join table could be null then I should put `and ... ` follow the join table right?

Comment: Right. That's how it is.

Comment: and if I want original table only return rows (must all related/left join table column equal what I desired or even null ) then I should put `and ...` at the final right?  (and this just like inner join )

Comment: Yes, indeed, the first table in the from clause (at the left of all the joins), should be filtered by conditions in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 2):

An outer join means that additionally to an inner join, when no match is found a mock record with all columns null gets joined.

So let's say for one mua we don't find a matching m. Then we get an m record with all columns null. m.status is null. With `WHERE m.status = $1` you dismiss that record, however, so you are where you were with a simple inner join.

Criteria on outer-joined tables belongs in the `ON` clause.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, so if I'm sure the join table are not null then I can put the `and ...` at the final or if the join table could be null then I should put `and ... ` follow the join table right?

Comment: The question is: Do you want to have mua records in your result for which not exist any m records with the desired status? If not, then you don't use a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, but a simple `[INNER] JOIN` and it doesn't really matter whether you have `m.status = $1` in `WHERE` or `ON`. If yes, you use a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` and criteria belongs in the `ON` clause.

Comment: I don't wnat mua show in result if other join table status not what match what I want or if other table row not exist, but I have to use left join for if m record exist, then output result match data structure what I want

Comment: No. `LEFT JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is a special join made especially to keep records with no match, an *outer* join. You however want a *normal* join, i.e. `INNER JOIN` or simply `JOIN`: `FROM media_user_action mua JOIN media m ON ...`.